# which jquery version supports Nokia Symbin OS

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, nokia

JQuery functionality not supporting in Nokia Symbin, Im using jquery-1.4.2.min.js version

Comment: Are you looking for [jQuery](http://jquerymobile.com/) *[Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/about/platforms.html)*?

Answer (score 1):

The latest Symbian browser supports HTML 5, CSS 3, JavaScript 1.8 so you should be able to use Jquery.

You could look at http://jquerymobile.com/